# What would give better performance? Business logic inside SP or in Business Layer?

Tags: performance

I am a newbie for architecture. I am really concerned about writing the business Logic inside the SP. But I am also worried about the sequence of round-trip calls it would made to DB If I write the entire business Logic in the Business Layer.?

Confused a lot. Which one will give more performance.

Note: both DB and App server could be scaled up as same level.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise can't see why it would make that much of a difference, given even feeble caching. The big problem doing it with SPs, is they tend to get dbms specific quick, they can be fragile and deployment and testing can be more of a pain than is needful.

I'd go with an ORM if I could, reserve SPs for special occasions.